# FetchRequest based on subset criteria

Tags: core-data, filter, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Consider the following object graph:

```
@objcMembers class Event: NSObject {
   let name: String
   let sections: [Section]
   init(name: String, sections: [Section]) {
      self.name = name
      self.sections = sections
   }
}
@objcMembers class Section: NSObject {
   let name: String
   let videos: [Video]
   init(name: String, videos: [Video]) {
      self.name = name
      self.videos = videos
   }
}
@objcMembers class Video: NSObject {
   let name: String
   let isFavorite: Bool
   let isWatched: Bool
   init(name: String, isFavorite: Bool, isWatched: Bool) {
      self.name = name
      self.isFavorite = isFavorite
      self.isWatched = isWatched
   }
}
```

I would like to filter the event sections which only have the videos marked as favorites

```
let events = [Event(name: "2021 Event",
                    sections: [
                        Section(name: "Monday",
                                videos: [Video(name: "VideoMonday1",
                                               isFavorite: true,
                                               isWatched: true),
                                         Video(name: "VideoMonday2",
                                               isFavorite: false,
                                               isWatched: true)]),
                        
                        Section(name: "Tuesday",
                                videos: [Video(name: "VideoTuesday1",
                                               isFavorite: false,
                                               isWatched: false),
                                         Video(name: "VideoTuesday2",
                                               isFavorite: true,
                                               isWatched: true)])
                    ])
]

//Expected result
let filtered =  [Event(name: "2021 Event",
                    sections: [
                        Section(name: "Monday",
                                videos: [Video(name: "VideoMonday1",
                                               isFavorite: true,
                                               isWatched: true)]),
                        
                        Section(name: "Tuesday",
                                videos: [Video(name: "VideoTuesday2",
                                               isFavorite: true,
                                               isWatched: true)])
                    ])
]
```

Im using CoreData, and i came up with this predicate:

```
let favPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(sections, $sect, SUBQUERY($sect.videos, $vid, $vid.isFavorite == YES).@count > 0).@count > 0")
```

This however doesnt exclude the videos which are not favorites, from the sections.
It s a query which runs on the event entity, and "it works" because it filters the array, but not what im looking for.
I can achieve this as soon as i get the root array: however, i d like to accomplish this using coreData, by not loading not needed objects in memory. Is this possible or its not worth in terms of complexity?

Comment: I think the main hurdle here is that you’re fetching Event objects but you want to exclude Video objects from the result and that goes against how Core Data relationships work as I see it. Maybe you could resolve this by returning a dictionary instead but I am pretty sure that is not what you want so I would personally take the easy way out here and use the existing predicate and then filter the videos in the view related code

Comment: @JoakimDanielson unfortunately, the event->section->video is a Logical/UI requirement: in fact, i cannot just show favorite videos, as it s strictly related to its section, which is itself related to the event

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you then, I thought you only wanted to include the favorite videos

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, it is. But i need to access the videos from a UI flow made by event->sections->videos. I just got an idea anyway: i could fetch videos, grouping them and access their source up to the event. This should be easier. I let you know

Comment: @JoakimDanielson considering adding a property source to video and section, i was able to fetch only the needed videos, using a specific predicate ("isFavorite == YES"). However, i had to rebuild the relationships, by using dictionary with groupingBy initializer. It was not that bad. At least, i only fetched the needed data